# Vscode remotely synchronizes multiple configuration files, lost

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

The current situation is like this, I have two computers A and B, A has not been turned on for a few days and the version is the previous version 1.80.0, but today I went to computer B to update the vs code to the latest version 1.81.0 At that time, my previous plug-ins were not synchronized as expected. At this time, when I went to update the Vscode version of computer A to 1.81.0, all my plug-in configuration files were lost, and the plug-in configuration files of A and B were all lost. Already! I have lost all the configuration files I have configured for so long, and I am very angry!

Under normal circumstances, when I update computer b, it should automatically synchronize the unsynchronized plug-ins of computer a. Why did I push the plug-in of a to the remote end! I am very angry, which caused me to configure it for a long time The config file needs to be reconfigured!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvb5s.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU2JN.png)